# anyone compared join performance between openjson and user defined table type?

Tags: t-sql

I use fair amount user defined table type in my code and it is relatively slow to join with other table when I put fairly big recordsets in (e.g. 100k).

I know openjson can also be used to accept list of objects and then join with other tables. I am just wondering which one has better performance? I could write my own tet but wondering if there are some more official performance benchamrks?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### nope

Joining to an amorphous blob that you have to parse at runtime will generally not improve performance, especially at the 100k row mark. Plan choice will matter here, if the JSON parse and join pushes the optimizer to choose a parallel plan (probably using a hash join), where the UDT join gets a serial plan (probably using nested loops).

The trouble with UDTs in SQL Server is that they're based on table variables, which have some repercussions when it comes to cardinality estimation, etc.

As an experiment, try creating a `#temp` table with the same definition as your UDT and dumping the data into that for use in queries where plan shape and cardinality estimation are important.

Other methods that may be of benefit:

- Add an `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` hint to any queries joining to the UDT
- Use dynamic SQL to assign an `OPTION(HASH JOIN)` hint when the number of records in your UDT exceeds some threshold
- If the UDT doesn't already have an index on join columns, add one to the definition

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Is there any doc on the benefit of adding index on UDT? I never thought about it before.

Comment: @jerryxu not specifically, no. It would be roughly the same as indexing any other table, with the caveat that table variables and by extension UDTs do not have statistics histograms created or maintained for them.